# users can APP using Telerik App Builder

Tags: api, telerik-appbuilder

I am writing an APP using Telerik App Builder. I want to have phone APP call functionality among users on APP.

Any idea/hint on how it can be achieved? do we have any API for this? The App will behave like Skype and the users can call each other? Any API/hint on this will be appreciated?

Thanks, 
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<a href="tel:xxx">call me</a>
```

This will bring up the device's native phone/dialing features (where "xxx" is the number you are calling).

Comment: Hi Rob, Thanks for reply. Its not like that. We are building app in that we want to have user to user call, we are using SignalR for real time chat, Can we have anything like API which will give me feature to call user as a audio call or video call just like Tango or skype using internet?